# Set a conditional based on names in a column of a data set

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Let’s keep only the three counties with the most observations: Sonoma, Los Angeles, and Kern. Create a conditional called `bigCounties` that is `TRUE` if the variable `county` is any of these three counties. Remember that `|` is the `or` logical operator.

UPDATE

```
bigCounties <- isTRUE( CASchools$county == "Sonoma" | CASchools$county == "Los Angeles"|CASchools$county == "Kern")
summary(bigCounties)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Mode   FALSE 
logical       1
```

How do I get it to run through the entire dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try `%in%`, e.g.,

```
CASchools$county %in% c("Sonoma", "Los Amgles", "Kern")
```

---

Otherwise, you should try

```
CASchools$county == "Sonoma"| CASchools$county == "Los Amgles"| CASchools$county =="Kern"
```

or (thank @akrun for the contribution)

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("Sonoma", "Los Amgles", "Kern"), function(x) CASchools$county == x))
```

if you want to use `|`

Comment: I got the or statements to work but its not running trough the full dataset just the first line